# Solar Low Current Disconnect Options

Tags: raspberry-pi, current-limiting, ldo, solar-charge-controller, esp32

I've built a system which allows me to remotely control a well pump which is directly connected to 24v solar array. There is a regulated battery bank/inverter, but it's farther away, and the pump is built for PV direct anyway.

My issues seemingly happen in the morning when solar output is enough to boot my controllers (a Raspberry Pi, Sonoff, and an ESP32 LoRa board). Should a condition (like retained MQTT commands) enable the relay to trigger I notice that it causes a boot loop or the Sonoff to go into an "I'm my own AP now" safe mode.

I'm powering this off a 24v->12v DC buck converter, but I'm fairly sure I need to add a low current dropout component, but I'm not sure what my options are for this. I see a lot of solar charge controllers that have over-current protection, as well as low voltage disconnects, but very little about low-current supply protection. Perhaps I am thinking about this the wrong way?

For specs, my load is a 400w motor controller, triggered by 2 big 12v relays in parallel, which are triggered by 5v relays driven by the Pi or Sonoff (all in parallel for reliability). Keeping power off, especially to the Sonoff until a minimum current would probably help, as it ends up in a safe mode, triggering it's relay to toggle.

Comment: A diagram of what you have and how things are connected would really help a lot.

Comment: It's not clear what "low current" you are refering to. It sounds like you probably need a method to measure the State of Charge of your batteries. That said, if your system does not have the reserve battery capacity to start the well pump after discharging during the night, you probably need bigger batteries or bigger solar panels. Please provide a diagram.

Comment: Will work on a diagram. Thanks!